# UnsatisfiedDependencyException when try to start JAR file

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle, javabeans

When I tried to run JAR file with command " java -jar ./artifacts/aqa-shop.jar -Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app " I got an Exception " UnsatisfiedDependencyException  ".

The error message is Error creating bean with name 'shopController' defined in URL, which suggests that there is a problem with the ShopController class. The ShopController class seems to  a dependency that cannot be satisfied, resulting in an " UnsatisfiedDependencyException ".

[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHwlx.png)
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMI5J.png)

I tried:

1. To change JAVA \ JDBC versions
2. Adding dependencies like "  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.1.RELEASE' "
3. Rewrite all projects with new Docker container

My CFG file ( application.properties ) is in the JAR file
My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1'
}

group 'ru.netology'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

allure {
    autoconfigure = true
    version = '2.13.3'

    useJUnit5 {
        version = '2.13.3'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    testImplementation 'com.codeborne:selenide:6.9.0'
    testImplementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testImplementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'
    testImplementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2'
    testImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-selenide:2.13.3'
}
configurations {
    testCompile
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty 'selenide.headless', System.getProperty('selenide.headless')
}
```

```
PS C:\Users\illya\IdeaProjects\DiplomRewrite> java -jar ./artifacts/aqa-shop.jar -Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2023-05-02 22:02:10.007  INFO 13256 --- [           main] ru.netology.shop.ShopApplication         : Starting ShopApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on LAPTOP-T3FMCA0A with PID 13256 (C:\Users\illya\IdeaProject
s\DiplomRewrite\artifacts\aqa-shop.jar started by illya in C:\Users\illya\IdeaProjects\DiplomRewrite)
2023-05-02 22:02:10.012  INFO 13256 --- [           main] ru.netology.shop.ShopApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-05-02 22:02:10.890  INFO 13256 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-02 22:02:10.975  INFO 13256 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 73ms. Found 3 repository interfaces.
2023-05-02 22:02:11.418  INFO 13256 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org
.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-05-02 22:02:11.921  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-02 22:02:11.936  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-02 22:02:11.937  INFO 13256 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2023-05-02 22:02:12.018  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-02 22:02:12.019  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1937 ms
2023-05-02 22:02:12.236  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-02 22:02:12.328  INFO 13256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
2023-05-02 22:02:12.493  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2023-05-02 22:02:12.621  INFO 13256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-02 22:02:12.854  INFO 13256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-02 22:02:12.878  INFO 13256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-05-02 22:02:13.509  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.N
oJtaPlatform]
2023-05-02 22:02:13.515  INFO 13256 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-02 22:02:13.774  WARN 13256 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.
beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shopController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/illya/IdeaProjects/DiplomRewrite/artifacts/aqa-shop.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/
ru/netology/shop/controller/ShopController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error cre
ating bean with name 'shopService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/illya/IdeaProjects/DiplomRewrite/artifacts/aqa-shop.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ru/netology/shop/service/ShopService.class]: Unexpected ex
ception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.credit-gate.url' in value "${spring.credit-gate.url}"
2023-05-02 22:02:13.775  INFO 13256 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-02 22:02:13.775  INFO 13256 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2023-05-02 22:02:13.780  INFO 13256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-02 22:02:13.788  INFO 13256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-05-02 22:02:13.790  INFO 13256 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-02 22:02:13.799  INFO 13256 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-02 22:02:13.805 ERROR 13256 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shopController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/illya/IdeaProjects/DiplomRewrite/artifacts/aqa-shop.jar
!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ru/netology/shop/controller/ShopController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreation
Exception: Error creating bean with name 'shopService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/illya/IdeaProjects/DiplomRewrite/artifacts/aqa-shop.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ru/netology/shop/service/ShopService.c
lass]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.credit-gate.url' in value "${spring.credit-gate.url}"      
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at ru.netology.shop.ShopApplication.main(ShopApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [aqa-shop.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [aqa-shop.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [aqa-shop.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [aqa-shop.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/illya/IdeaProjects/DiplomRewrite/artifacts/aqa-shop.jar!
/BOOT-INF/classes!/ru/netology/shop/service/ShopService.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.cr
edit-gate.url' in value "${spring.credit-gate.url}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:530) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.credit-gate.url' in value "${spring.credit-gate.url}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:908) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: _"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.credit-gate.url' in value "${spring.credit-gate.url}""_ your configuration is incomplete. It is missing a value for `spring.credit-gate.url`.